# Prove that Urysohn spaces are completely Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Theorem:
>
> Urysohn spaces are $T_{2\frac{1}{2}}$.

My attempt: Let $(X, \tau)$ be an Urysohn space. Let $u, v$ be distinct points in $X$. Let $f$ be an Urysohn function for $\{u\}$ and $\{v\}$. Then the inverse image of an open interval $]0, p[$ is open(By continuity). However I cannot show that $f^{-1}]0, p[ \cup \{u\}$ is also open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a continuous $f:X\to[0,1]$ such that $f(u)=0$ and $f(v)=1$. You want to use that to get disjoint closed nbhds of $u$ and $v$; consider the sets

$$f^{-1}\left[\left[0,\frac13\right]\right]\qquad\text{and}\qquad f^{-1}\left[\left[\frac23,1\right]\right]\;.$$

Comment: How do you show that $u$ is contained in the interior of the first set?

Comment: @Henry: It’s in the open set $f^{-1}\left[\left[0,\frac13\right)\right]$.